# Ansible use dict and string with combine function

Tags: ansible

I have a problem that I don't understand, more precisely I would like to understand the cause of the problem and therefore also the solution.

I have an Ansible-Playbook for my nfs mounts.
If I run this playbook I get the message:

`["{{ { dest: '/xxx', src: '//123.234.234.123/xxx' }| combine(NFS_RO) }}"]: 'dest' is undefined`

```
---
- hosts: localhost

vars:
  MOUNT_XXX: { dest: '/xxx', src: '//123.234.234.123/xxx' }

  NFS_RO: { fstype: 'nfs', mount_opts: 'yyyy', owner: 'me', group: 'me', mode: 'u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX', state: mounted }

  MOUNT_MOUNTPOINTS:
    - "{{ { dest: '/xxx', src: '//123.234.234.123/xxx' } | combine(NFS_RO) }}"

tasks:
- name: Configure and mount
  mount:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    path: "{{ item.dest }}"
    fstype: "{{ item.fstype }}"
    opts: "{{ item.mount_opts }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
  with_items:
    "{{ MOUNT_MOUNTPOINTS }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.src }}  =>  {{ item.dest }}"
```

But when I change the playbook and use the variable `MOUNT_XXX` everything works like exacted.

Can someone explain to me where the error lies or what I need to do differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing you would like to create several mountpoints with the same set of parameters in a loop, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    MOUNTPOINTS:
      - src: '//192.0.2.1/test-net-1'
        dest: '/test-net-1'
      - src: '//198.51.100.1/test-net-2'
        dest: '/test-net-2'
      - src: '//203.0.113.1/test-net-3'
        dest: '/test-net-3'

    NFS_PARAMETER:
      fstype: 'nfs'
      mount_opts: 'defaults'
      owner: 'me'
      group: 'me'
      mode: 'u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX'
      state: 'mounted'

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: |
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        path: "{{ item.dest }}"
        fstype: "{{ NFS_PARAMETER.fstype }}"
        opts: "{{ NFS_PARAMETER.mount_opts }}"
        state: "{{ NFS_PARAMETER.state }}"
    loop: "{{ MOUNTPOINTS }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/test-net-1', u'src': u'//192.0.2.1/test-net-1'}) =>
  msg: |-
    src: "//192.0.2.1/test-net-1"
    path: "/test-ent-1"
    fstype: "nfs"
    opts: "defaults"
    state: "mounted"
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/test-net-2', u'src': u'//198.51.100.1/test-net-2'}) =>
  msg: |-
    src: "//198.51.100.1/test-net-2"
    path: "/test-net-2"
    fstype: "nfs"
    opts: "defaults"
    state: "mounted"
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/test-net-3', u'src': u'//203.0.113.1/test-net-3'}) =>
  msg: |-
    src: "//203.0.113.1/test-net-3"
    path: "/test-net-3"
    fstype: "nfs"
    opts: "defaults"
    state: "mounted"
```

If that's the case you might also be interested in [Module defaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html).